# How to cut and paste information cell by cell from one worksheet to another in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

So I cut and paste the income statement into an `excel` spreadsheet, and I was hoping to make a macro that would run in a loop and check each cell one-by-one to see if they had data in it, and if it had data, to cut and paste it to another sheet.

This is the foundation of a bigger project, but I am just stuck on this. I also feel that with the looping code working, I can tweak it to do some of the other stuff I need to do.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked in to looping cells in a range? What has/hasn't worked?

Answer (score 0):

To get started in writing a macro like this, it easiest to record the actions you're performing and the review/edit the code. When recording, perform the fewest actions as possible, including avoiding scrolling, so that the code that is generated relates to only the actions you require.

To copy and paste all data excluding blank cells, try using Paste Special and put a tick against Skip Blanks.